# How do I display clean output in Visual studio code with out path or "You may only use..." disclaimer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have this simple code in Visual Studio Code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!"); 
    }
}
```

All I want to do is get the same result as when I type DOTNET RUN which prints a simple "Hello!!!" to the terminal.

Instead, if i configure it to use the terminal, I get this PATH in blue or if I try to use the debug window, I get this "You may only use..." disclaimer.

How can I set my configuration to either use one of these windows by clicking "Start with out debugging"  (not via typing dotnet run manually) to print my output with out any excess info in the red boxes as seen in the images?

If there's a way to configure "dotnet run" in my settings, i'm good with that too so long the output is just "Helloo!!!" on either the debug or terminal window.

[image] [image]

Comment: Do not post screenshots of text (code, data, whatever) - it is deprecated/forbidden here.

Answer (score 1):

For Python i tried the method below.

In Visual Studio Code, click on the file and then click “RUN” at the top. find “Add Configuration” button on the menu and create a launch.json file by clicking on it. In the file, you will the line ”console”: integratedTerminal . Now change it to “console”:internalConsole. Open your code file and click “RUN” at the top again. Finally if you click on “Run without debugging” button, the output of your code will be display in “Debug Console” at where the terminal is.

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this by using an extension like **Code Runner** which works with Visual Studio Code, it is similar to **Script Runner** which works with the Atom editor. These are useful for reviewing simple code changes in real-time.

Comment: I tried it with python and it too write extra stuff to the output... i.e. 

[Running] python "c:\CSharp2Python\Python_VSC\Program.py"
(Hello!!!)
[Done] exited with code=0 in